# Reverting Back to Inline Style on Button Click - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a ul li grid on a page that has inline styles being applied to it from a plugin. There are options to select above this list that hides/displays none on them if a checkbox doesn't apply to the item.

I am trying to add a 'reset' button that reverts those styles back to normal, as they were on page load, so it is like the checkbox selection didn't happen.

Here is an example of one style on page load. Notice they are being set from the top and left of the page so I cannot hardcode a specific attribute - this is from the plugin.

```
position: absolute;
left: 330px;
top: 1320px;
```

I know I can remove the styles all together with jQuery but I don't know if it's possible to revert the inline styles back as they were on pageload.

Comment: Well you'd first of all have to _read_ the values, before your plugin does its thing - because otherwise, they are simply lost when the plugin overwrites them.

Comment: The inline styles are being set from the plugin not from the stylesheet. The plugin is positioning them absolute and top/bottom pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var default_styles = new Array();

    default_styles = $('ul li').map(function(){ return $(this).attr('style') }).get();

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('ul li').each(function( i,v ){
            $(v).attr('style', default_styles[i] )
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle added : https://jsfiddle.net/ehpmvqL7/3/

Comment: @runningantelope123 Glad that could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky but you could read out the values of the element's style attribute using the `.attr()` method on your jquery object before the plugin modifies the inline styles.

Then, you could reference those stored "original styles" however you want later on in your code (such as setting them back after the checkbox is clicked).